# Overriding Mage_Wishlist_IndexController in Magento

Tags: php, magento, overriding

Hi i am trying to override magento wishlist **IndexController**. I have followed all steps but its not working here is my code and path of all directories

> app\code\local\XS4Arabia\Wishlist\etc\config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>  
    <modules>      
        <XS4Arabia_Wishlist>          
            <version>0.1.0</version>      
        </XS4Arabia_Wishlist>  
    </modules>    
    <frontend>      
        <routers>          
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                  <modules>
                    <XS4Arabia_Wishlist before="Mage_Wishlist">XS4Arabia_Wishlist</XS4Arabia_Wishlist>
                  </modules>
                </args>
          </wishlist>      
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app\code\local\XS4Arabia\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php

```
    require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Wishlist') . DS . 'IndexController.php';
    class XS4Arabia_Wishlist_IndexController extends Mage_Wishlist_IndexController
    {
      public function sendAction()
       {
        die('local');
       }
    }
```

> app\etc\modules\XS4arabia_Wishlist.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <XS4Arabia_Wishlist>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </XS4Arabia_Wishlist>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: first of all, you need remove the space before <?xml tag, with that it doesn't show module in sys->conf->adv->disable module section.

Comment: `app\etc\modules\XS4arabia_Wishlist.xml` needs to be named `app\etc\modules\XS4Arabia_Wishlist.xml`